# Pandas/Python how to create an average for specif variable values?

Tags: python, database, if-statement, average, pandas-groupby

I am new using Pandas/python and I would like to know, when I have a dataset, how I can create an average from a variable, volume, for each value of another variable, price, if variable hour is between some specific values, lets say 1 to 10. To understand better what I have is the following:

[image: excel-columns]

I what I want to obtain is the following price and volume columns in green; which are the average of volume for each price when 1<=hour<=10.

[image: result]

I would really appreciate your help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Quick tip: if you post a question, please provide started code on how to create the dataframe (rather than posting a screenshot) because it makes it easier for the people helping you.

Step 1: filter your dataframe using a mask

Step 2: create new dataframe using mask

Step 3: use groupby object

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Hour': [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 16, 16, 16],
    'Price': [-3000, -262, 150, -3000, -262, 150, -3000, -262, 150],
    'Volume': [8133, 28287, 19289, 20242, 19428, 28322, 18147, 17234, 12133],
})

print('Raw dataframe:')
print(df, '\n')

# first create a mask that filters the data you want
mask_hour_1to10 = df['Hour'].between(1, 10)

# second create a new dataframe with the mask
df_filtered = df.loc[mask_hour_1to10]

print('Filtered dataframe:')
print(df_filtered, '\n')

# third, use a groupby object on price, to calculate average of volume
df_groupby_mean = df_filtered.groupby('Price')['Volume'].mean()

print('Groupby Object:')
print(df_groupby_mean)
```

[image]